# set an array of enum

Tags: java, reflection

I have a little helper util that reads a csv into a pojo. For the most part it works really fine. Now I have an issue with enums.

I am able to fill:

- an enum
- a list of enums
- an array

But I have a problem with an array of enums. Here is a code snippet of some of these special cases:

```
public void fillPojo(Object pojo) {
    // use setter/getter as well - using beanutils
    for(PropertyDescriptor pd : PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(pojo.getClass())) {
        if(pd.getName().equals("class")|| pd.getReadMethod() == null)
            continue;

        // get the value (based on the property name)
        String value = this.get(pd.getName());
        if(value == null || value.equals("null"))
            continue;
        try {
            // this works for normal lists and list of any enum
            if(pd.getPropertyType().isAssignableFrom(List.class)) {
                List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
                for(String s : value.split(","))
                    values.add(s);
                pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(pojo, ConvertUtils.convert(values, pd.getPropertyType()));
            }
            else if(pd.getPropertyType().isArray()) {
               ///////////////////////// this throws a conversionException
                List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
                for(String s : value.split(","))
                    values.add(s);
                Object[] objs = new Object[values.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
                    if(StringUtils.isBlank(values.get(i)))
                        objs[i] = null;
                    else {
                        objs[i] = ConvertUtils.convert(values.get(i), pd.getPropertyType().getComponentType());
                    }
                }
                pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(pojo, objs);
               /////////////////////////

            }
            else
            if(pd.getPropertyType().isEnum()) {
                if(StringUtils.isEmpty(value) || "null".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                    pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(pojo, (Object)null);
                else
                    pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(pojo, Enum.valueOf(pd.getPropertyType().asSubclass(Enum.class), value));
            }
            else
                pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(pojo, ConvertUtils.convert(value, pd.getPropertyType()));
        } catch (NullPointerException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | ConversionException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.err.println("'" + pojo.getClass().getSimpleName() + "' Problem while setting: " + pd.getName() + " with value " + value + " type: " + pd.getPropertyType().getSimpleName() + ":" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
     }
```

I tried different approaches to create the enum, but I cannot seem to be able to correctly create a list of enums and setting them without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you pass into the setter an array of invalid type, e.g. you have bean setter:

```
public void setMyEnumArray(MyEnum[] array) {...}
```

then your call of 'pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(pojo, objs)' would be similar to:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[values.size()];
...
pojo.setMyEnumArray(objs);
```

Thus, you should convert Object[] into MyEnum[] before calling this setter:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[values.size()];
...
objs = Arrays.copyOf(objs, objs.length, (Class) pd.getPropertyType());
pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(pojo, objs);
```